# Couldn't free allocated memory using delete

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qlist

I'm allocating memory in a member function like below:

```
void Wrapper::PutData() {

mpeople.append(new people("ALPHA","BEETA","GAMMA", this));
mpeople.append(new people("ALPHA","BEETA","GAMMA", this));
mpeople.append(new people("ALPHA","BEETA","GAMMA", this));

}
```

where the `mpeople` object is declared as

```
QList<QObject*> mpeople;
```

Everything works fine until i try to remove items using the below member-function

```
void Wrapper::RemoveClient(int index){
    if(index >= 0){
        delete[] mpeople[index];
        mpeople.removeAt(index);
    }
    resetModel();
}
```

Comment: Also recommend a test to ensure `index` is not larger than `mpeople`.

Comment: @user4581301 - that's a very excellent point. But I would surmise it would be a bug in the code if `index` was ever out of range to begin with such that the range check prevented a crash. Better to let the code assert/crash than hide a real bug.

Comment: Agreed. `assert`'s probably the right way to go. Otherwise the abort would have to be manual. I don't think `removeAt` check and throws an exception for out-of-bounds access.

Comment: When you create object(s) using `new[]` use `delete[]` to release, but when you create by `new` use `delete`. It is quite easy to remember.

Comment: Why not have a QList of QObject instead of the extra indirection? At least with std::list I would do that and use emplace_back to avoid unecessary copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to do scalar delete on an object that wasn't allocated with scalar new.  That is `delete`, not `delete []`.

Just do this:

```
void Wrapper::RemoveClient(int index){
    if(index >= 0){
        delete mpeople[index];
        mpeople.removeAt(index);
    }
    resetModel();
}
```

A more modern way, is to use shared_ptr or unique_ptr or the equivalent qt smart pointer class.

Declare like this:

```
QList<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> mpeople;
```

Insert like this:

```
mpeople.append(std::make_shared<people>("ALPHA","BEETA","GAMMA", this));
```

Remove like this:

```
mpeople.removeAt(index); // pointer will get deleted for you when the last reference goes away
```